# Calculating Total of Column in Header Section in Acumatica Report Designer

Tags: report, acumatica, designer

I am fairly new to Report Designer and I have a requirement where they want the total of a column in the header section, this should print only on the first page and values considered should be where page index = page count, how can I fulfill this?

Comment: Which column do you wish to sum?  If you want a value in standard DAC like PO, ARInvoice, ect....those DACs usually have their own Total column.  So no need to write your own.

Comment: @ChrisH I created a report variable of my own, since there is a calculation involved in it. In that scenario how can I get total in header?

Comment: Not sure what the issue is but if the total shows as 0 you might have to change ProcessOrder property to Always instead of WhileRead.